# Replication of Replication

Tags: postgresql, database-replication

I have 3 servers running CentOS+PG 11 (postgresql11-server-11.5-1PGDG.rhel7.x86_64):

- s1: main db + publication
- s2: subscription of the main db

all works fine until here...
Now, I tried to config this:

- s2: publication of the same db that was replicated from s1
- s3: subscription of the db from s2

When I did this, replication s1=>s2 stopped, and replication s2=>s3 never worked.

Is this not possible?

Comment: Could you share more context?  What kind of errors do you see in the logs, and what steps did you take to build this replication cluster?

Comment: I just created the normal commands of publication and subscription. No errors in log file after the second part of the configuration s2=>s3, but after this just s1=>s2 stopped.